# Lock the orientation to landscape in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

My app has navigation set up and it is a single activity app.
Fragments are linked like this:

`MainFragment` -> `GameFragment`

`MainFragment` -> `GameSetupFragment` -> `GameFragment`

What I need to accomplish: Depending on settings, GameFragment sometimes should be locked in the landscape mode. When I did this in an activity, I wrote a line of code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

What can I do if I use fragments? Is there a way to tell the fragment owner (i.e. the activity) to switch the orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you know that your fragment is attached to the activity, you can call `requireActivity()` in the fragment to get your activity:

```kotlin
requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```